# Load a http page from a local file

Tags: html

What can I place within a local .html file which when opened in a browser will redirect to a Http website?

For the life of me I can not figure out the simplest way to do this. Do I really need a javascript redirect?

Many thanks.
Ben

Comment: Google is your best friend, http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml

Comment: This is important to note: `Not all browsers support the Meta "refresh" function, so it's always a good idea to include a clickable link to the new or correct URL`.

Comment: @xbonez do you have enough experience to know which browsers do not support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use a META in the HEAD to redirect;

```
  <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://someurl.com/foo/bar">
```

Here http://someurl.com/foo/bar is the target url and 5 is the number of seconds to wait before redirecting